# Connect a protected access database to sql server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I Have a password-protected access database (.mdb) and sql server 2008 running in windows server 2008 R2 x64.

I installed "Microsost Access Database Engine" and I want to create a linked server to access, but I get this error:

> "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user".

there is not any *.mdw file on my server.

I'm able to add a linked server to an unprotected database, but not to a protected database.

How can I add a mdw file without install MS access?

or is there any oher way to add a linked server?

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'Access', @srvproduct=N'Access', @provider=N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
 @datasrc=N'C:\Program Files\ZKTime5.0\att2000.mdb'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'Access',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'Admin',@rmtpassword=''
```

this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I am okay with the SQL script for creating linked servers:

```
////////////////Create linked server with no password access file
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'linkedserver', @srvproduct=N'Smarthr', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'dbpath\file.mdb'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINKEDSVR',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

//////////////////////////Create linked server with access password file
exec sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = 'LinkServer', 
    @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    @srvproduct = 'Access4',
    @datasrc = 'dbpath\filename.mdb', 
    @provstr = ';PWD=yourpassword'

exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = 'LinkServer',
    @useself = 'FALSE',
    @locallogin = null, 
    @rmtuser = 'Admin', 
    @rmtpassword = null
```